# True of False: For any $I_n$ and any $A \in \Bbb R^{n\times n}$, $(I_n + A)(I_n − A) = I_n − A^2$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Not sure if the following statement is true or false:

For any $I_n$ and any $A \in \Bbb R^{n\times n}$, $(I_n + A)(I_n − A) = I_n − A^2$

I am thinking true because: 
$(I_n + A)(I_n - A) = I_n*I_n - I_n*A + A*I_n - A*A = I_n - A + A - A^2 = I_n - A^2$

Comment: Your analysis is correct.

Comment: Nothing wrong there. As a tip, all factoring rules and algorithms such as difference of squares or binomial expansion apply if the matrices involved all commute with each other.

Comment: And to add to @NinadMunshi 's comment, note that $A$ always commutes with all of its powers (including $A^0=I_n$).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your working is correct. It is good that you thought about the non-commutativity of matrices in general.